# In PostgreSQL, how can I optimize a query with which I obtain the differences between the current column and the immediately previous one?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, row, difference

I have this audit table

| User | date | text | text 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| u1 | 2023-01-01 | hi | yes |
| u1 | 2022-12-20 | hi | no |
| u1 | 2022-12-01 | hello | maybe |

And I need as a result, something like this:

| User | date | text | text 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| u1 | 2023-01-01 | null | x |
| u1 | 2022-12-20 | x | x |
| u1 | 2022-12-01 | null | null |

So I can know which column changed from the last time.

Something like this is working, but I think may be a way to optimize it? or at least generate a "more easy to look" query? (i need the information for almost 20 columns, not only 3)

```
SELECT 
    ta.audit_date,
    ta.audit_user,
    CASE
        WHEN ta.audit_operation = 'I' THEN 'Insert'
        WHEN ta.audit_operation = 'U' THEN 'Update'
    END AS action,
    CASE WHEN ta.column1 <> (SELECT column1
                                    FROM audit_table ta1
                                    WHERE ta1.id = 9207 AND ta1.audit_date < ta.audit_date
                                    ORDER BY ta1.audit_date DESC
                                    LIMIT 1) 
        THEN 'X' ELSE null END column1,
    CASE WHEN ta.column2 <> (SELECT column2
                                    FROM audit_table ta1
                                    WHERE ta1.id = 9207 AND ta1.audit_date < ta.audit_date
                                    ORDER BY ta1.audit_date DESC
                                    LIMIT 1) 
        THEN 'X' ELSE null END column2,
    CASE WHEN ta.column3 <> (SELECT column3
                                    FROM audit_table ta1
                                    WHERE ta1.id = 9207 AND ta1.audit_date < ta.audit_date
                                    ORDER BY ta1.audit_date DESC
                                    LIMIT 1) 
        THEN 'X' ELSE null END column3
FROM
    audit_table ta
WHERE
    ta.id = 9207
ORDER BY
    audit_date DESC
```

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps my english, what i want to do, is compare current row with prior row, detect diferences, mark them, and get that as a result. I got a "solution", but i think (i don't know how) to optimize it. Multiple similar subqueries with limit is ugly to sea, ugly to mantain, and i think its slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just use the `LAG()` analytic function here.  If I understand correctly:

```sql
SELECT *, CASE WHEN text != LAG(text) OVER (ORDER BY date) THEN 'x' END AS text_label,
          CASE WHEN text2 != LAG(text) OVER (ORDER BY date) THEN 'x' END AS text2_label
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: Perfect!!! i don't know that function exists! Thanks!